# JavaFX : Does WebView support geolocation?

Tags: javascript, java, html, webview, javafx-2

I am currently doing project in JavaFX with the use of WebView. My application is expected to retrieve currrent location (lattitude and longitude) of the user. I am trying to use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);` in the WebView via html file, but it doesn't seem to be working.
Does WebView support geolocation? If not, what methods can I apply to retrieve the location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, WebView does not support Geolocation.

Loading https://html5test.com up in a Webview reports a negative on Geolocation support:

[image: geolocation support]

System tested was: Java 8u72, OS X 10.9.5, MacBook Pro Retina 2015.

> If not, what methods can I apply to retrieve the location?

I do not have any suggestions.